# Git log excluding branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-log

Consider the following commit history:

```
1---R---3---5---P->                  # patch-v1.1
     \       \
      2---4---+---8---+---10---R->   # release-v2.0
           \         /
            6---7---9                # feature-foo

--> time

# 1 - 10 are commits
# P is a patch release commit
# R are major release commits
# + marks a merge commit
```

I want to generate the changelog for `release-v2.0`, but since `P (patch-v1.1)` has already been released, it's changes should not be part of the `v2.0` changelog. Can I configure the `git log` command to only list commits `2, 4, 6 .. 11` (i.e., commits from `release-v2.0` and `feature-foo`)?

Comment: I haven't tested it (yet), but I assume it doesn't, seeing that I sometimes merged `patch-v1.1` commits into the `release-v2.0` branch.

Comment: Oh, didn't notice the patch merge, then what about `git log P..R`?

Comment: Does that include `2, 4, 6 and 7` as well? They chronologically happened before `P`.

Comment: You can find more information at `git help rev-parse` (SPECIFYING RANGES).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `git log R --not P`. That's the same as `git log P..R` from @micha-wiedenmann's comment, but I find the former syntax more speaking. And yes, it will include `2, 4, 6, 7, 9` as it does not matter when they chronologically happened (in terms of time authored), but where they are in the DAG. With `R --not P` you basically create the complement of P in R in terms of set theory.

Comment: So as not to get the merge comments identified as `+` in the DAG above, you should likely also include the `--no-merges` option. Merge commits don't usually contribute meaningful information to a changelog.